# how to remove or insert into a Javascript multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

I have a 2-dimensional data structure like this:

```
    var arr = [
        {
            'subarr': [
                { 'a': '11' },
                { 'a': '12' }
            ]
        },
        {
            'subarr': [
                { 'a': '21' },
                { 'a': '22' }
            ]
        },
        {
            'subarr': [
                { 'a': '31' },
                { 'a': '32' }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

I need to insert an element, e.g. '23', or remove, e.g. '22'.

The `slice` method does not copy the entire data, but inserts or removes in the array 'in place'. But how do I apply that on a 2-dim array? This code will **not work**, because the [i] operation creates a new variable, so `arr` will not be changed at all:

```
arr[1].subarr.slice(0, 1);
```

I would need some reference type of variable to point at the subarray to be sliced.

Any help would be appreciated

---

As happens more often: the complicated problem has a simple answer. I should have used `splice()`, not `slice()`, as the answers told me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add `push(), []`, `splice()` or `unshift()`

```
arr[1].subarr.push({'a':'23'}); //add at the end
```

or

```
arr[1].subarr.unshift({'a':'23'}); //add in the beginig
```

to add at specific position (2th in this case)

```
arr[1].subarr.splice(2, 0, {'a':'433'}, {'a':'544'});
```

to remove splice

```
arr[1].subarr.splice(1,1); //splice(start,deleteCount)
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solutions will return only the 2nd arr element, with the modified data. The variable 'arr' will not be changed.

Comment: Anything that starts with `arr[i]` will obviously not work. I need a solution for the problem of changing the variable `arr`.

Comment: @Roland arr[1].subarr.slice(0, 1); modifies arr

Comment: I tested with console.log, and with `alert('arr[1].length = ' + arr[1].subarr.length);` but the var 'arr' is NOT changed :-(

Comment: `splice` will actually modify your array not `slice`;

Comment: @Roland that's because arr[1] is always the same object with the property subarr you should do arr[1].subarr.length

Comment: @Hikmat yes it's arr[1].subarr.splice(0, 1); I made a mistake in the comment

Answer (score 1):

> How to insert an element ie '23' without *mutation*:

```js
    var arr = [
        {
            'subarr': [
                { 'a': '11' },
                { 'a': '12' }
            ]
        },
        {
            'subarr': [
                { 'a': '21' },
                { 'a': '22' }
            ]
        },
        {
            'subarr': [
                { 'a': '31' },
                { 'a': '32' }
            ]
        }
    ];
    
    var newArr = [...arr, arr[0].subarr.push({'a':'23'})]
    console.log(newArr)
```

> How to remove an element ie '22' without *mutation*:

```js
    var arr = [
        {
            'subarr': [
                { 'a': '11' },
                { 'a': '12' }
            ]
        },
        {
            'subarr': [
                { 'a': '21' },
                { 'a': '22' }
            ]
        },
        {
            'subarr': [
                { 'a': '31' },
                { 'a': '32' }
            ]
        }
    ];

var newArr = [...arr.map(element => element.subarr.filter(item => item.a !== '22'))]

console.log(newArr)
```